# Why does clang-format destroy Unicode characters within eclipse?

Tags: c++, unicode, eclipse-cdt, code-formatting, clang-format

I am using Eclipse CDT Eclipse C/C++ Development Tools 10.2.0.202103011047,   CppStyle 1.5.0.0 and `clang-format` from clang 12.0.0.

My C++ source file contains a line

```
QString fileExportDirectory = "./";
```

because I am writing a unit test for handling Unicode paths. As soon as I format any part of the file, the line gets changed into

```
QString fileExportDirectory = "./?";
```

Why does that happen? Both, the encoding of the respective file and the default text file encoding are set to "UTF-8". I have not read anything that `clang-format` or Cppstyle have difficulties with Unicode. How can I prevent my `clang-format` code formatter from destroying Unicode contents?

Comment: What operating system are you on? And does running `clang-format` from the command line corrupt the file, with Eclipse completely out of the picture?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Windows 10. I have tried it: `clang-format` alone does not corrupt the file... interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described misbehaviour is a reported CppStyle bug (https://github.com/wangzw/CppStyle/issues/39). As a workaround

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

can be added to "eclipse.ini", then formatting works as expected.